# An improper integral in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following problem:

> Let $A:=\{u\in\Bbb R^3:r\le|u|\le1\}$ for $r\in(0,1)$. Compute the limit: 
> $$\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_{A}{1\over {|u|}}$$
> if it exists. If it does not, explain.

I may think this limit does not exist since when $|r|\to0$, the term ${1\over |u|}$ goes to infinity which is not Riemann integrable, and then the limit does not exist.

Am I approaching this problem right? Thanks!

Comment: HINT: using spherical coordinates would help.

Comment: take volume of $A$ as a function of $r$. Then $dA=Cr^2dr$, $C$ as constant. Integral as $\int_{ 0\le r\le 1}\dfrac{1}{r}dA$

Comment: @ShuhaoCao But the problem is that we have not learned anything about the spherical coordinate. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Scorpio19891119 huh? I thought the Riemann integral in spherical coordinates precede the real analysis course, this together with dominated convergence theorem would give you the limit. (Write the integral as $\displaystyle \int_{\{0<|u|<1\}} I_{\{r<|u|<1\}} \frac{1}{|u|}$ first)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use spherical coordinates and bring the problem back to the convergence of
$$
\int_0^1r^\alpha dr
$$
in $\mathbb{R}$.
For which values of $\alpha$ does this converge? What is $\alpha$ in your case?